# Semi-automated NightmareJS -> ability to view/interact with Electron browser window on Lambda

Tags: lambda, automation, electron, nightmare

I'm looking to see if there's a way to view, and more importantly, interact with the Electron browser display when running NightmareJS automation on AWS Lambda (or if not on Lambda, a web server I set up).

I've successfully set up multiple Nightmare automation jobs on Lambda, and off, and while full automation is definitely the ideal, there are times when a real human must interact with a given web page to move past a certain point- i.e. a Captcha form that must be completed (anti-automation bot blockers testing for a "real human").

I have dreamed up this "semi-automated" approach that would basically "nightmare.wait()" for the User to interact with the browser, then return to full automation afterwards.

A high-level example would be something like this:

1. Nightmare goto login page
2. Nightmare fills in login form credentials and waits for the real human user to hit the submit button, and then possibly completes a Captcha form manually, too.
3. Once completed (login successful), the Nightmare automation could determine it's past its "waiting point" and then the "full automation" (no human interaction necessary) would take over from there.

I have already implemented this locally and tested it successfully (setting Nightmare/Electron webPreferences config option "show" to true, then interacting with the web pages shown in the browser window while it "waits" for the next automated step), so I know the semi-automatic aspect of it works.

However, the part I'm unsure about is how to replicate this when the Nightmare automation is running on Lambda. Is there any way for me to show the Electron browser window and interact with it when its on Lambda? If not, if I put the Nightmare automation on my own web server, would there be a way for me to view and interact with the Electron browser window through an iframe in a real web browser (or some other similar way)?

I haven't seen a single example, or even mention, of anything like this on the web yet, but being able to achieve this would greatly enhance the capabilities of web automation. Getting around "bot blockers" and other anti-automation roadblocks would be much more feasible when it truly thinks a human is interacting with it (which it would be) than straight automation.

Comment: Lambda is very limited and contained area for running specific function with a very small time limit. It is impractical in a way to run GUI on lambda. Maybe you can try uDocker or something.

Comment: Yeah, the Lambda aspect isn't a requirement bc of the feasibility issues mentioned. Preferably, I'd like to just run Nightmare automation _client-side_ using something like Browserify, but I'm still trying to figure this out. The core thing I want is the ability to interact with the Electron window while running Nightmare automation on the client (not locally/server-side).